# Using Codeigniter to achieve alphabetical lists

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've searched high and low for the answer to this, alas, it has avoided me like a hot girl on prom night.

I'm essentially building a directory that my client requested that require Alphabetized headers followed by the names of categories. Here's a little twist, I'm using codeigniter.

I have a basic model function that grabs all of the main categories by name.

```
function getAllMainCats(){
   $this->db->from('main_categories');
   $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');

   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

And this is where I get horribly stuck.
I've seen a couple of different results online, but I haven't been able to modify them with any success into working with Codeigniter.

With pseudocode, this is how I imagined it would work

```
getAllMainCategories
foreach( mainCategories as mainCategory){
   grabfirstletterofeachcategory;
   putThatIntoArray();
   Count amount of items in new array
   display that amount of lists
   apply links according to the foreach loop as maincategory.

}
```

essentially

```
<li>
   <h3>A</h3>
   <a href='/'>Almond</a>
   <a href='/'>Apple</a>
   <a href='/'>Artichoke</a>
</li>

<li>
   <h3>B</h3>
   <a href='/'>Bacon</a>
   <a href='/'>Banana</a>
   <a href='/'>Beans</a>
</li>
```

ETC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, is not that far from your pseudocode:

```
$categories = $this->mymodel->getAllMainCats();
$ordered = array();
foreach($categories as $cat){
 $first = strtoupper($cat[0]);
 $ordered[$first][] = $cat;
}
```

You should have an array like:

```
array( A => array(  0 => Almond, 1 => Apple..),
       B => array(  0 => Banana...),
```

So now you loop over that:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($ordered as $key => $value): ?>
<?php // outer loop over the keys, i.e. the letters: ?>
 <li>
   <h3><?php echo $key;?></h3>
   <ul>
   <?php foreach($value as $val):?>
   <?php // inner loop over the values, i.e. the elements:?>
    <li><a href='/'><?php echo $val;?></a></li>
   <?php endforeach;?>
  </ul>
 </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://codepad.org/zlXqR8vw)

Comment: Thanks! I actually managed to figure it out myself in the long run, but this is basically what my end result ended up being. Thanks for solidifying my answer, at least I know that I didn't achieve the goal in an unorthodox way.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying this is the most orthodox way. It surely does what it needs do, but there might be better actions, like saving the first letter in the database so to make better queries, or to cache and paginate the results, and so on...But that depends on your design and overall structure of your application. First step is always making it work, optimization comes next